# [rosparam] do not overwrite an existing param or default value

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm looking for a way to specify a DEFAULT value for /some/parameter on the parameter server in a XML launch file.
In other terms if it's already there I don't want to overwrite the previous value.

Also is it possible to test any other variable than a bool?
I would like to do something like:

```
  <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
  <node if="$(arg method)==nearest" name="point_provider" pkg="point_providers" type="simple_publisher.py" />
  <node if="$(arg method)==regression" name="point_provider" pkg="regression_models" type="publisher.py" />
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Also a complete control structure if/elif/else would be nice.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197684/%5Brosparam%5D-do-not-overwrite-an-existing-param-or-default-value/) by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 454 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Avoiding parameter override seems to be not possible but in #q173575 some workarounds are suggested.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0